# Variables declared inside other functions are not working in main python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is supposed to print a menu for the user, have them choose an option, and depending on which option they choose, they enter a number with a certain base. I need a function to gather their option, a function to gather their number once they've entered a choice, and a function to validate that their number is in the correct base. I keep getting an error because the variable "userChoice" that I declare in one of my functions is "undefined" when I try to use it in main. How can I fix this?

```
def printmenu(userChoice):
    flag = True

    while(flag == True):
        print("Enter 2 for base 2")
        print("Enter 8 for base 8")
        print("Enter 16 for base 16")
        userChoice = input("Enter 0 to stop: ")

        if userChoice not in ["2", "8", "16", "0"]:
            print("Invalid choice\n")
            flag = True
        else:
            flag = False
    return(userChoice)

def askUserValue():
    flag2 = False

    while(flag == True):
        base2 = input("Enter a base 2 number: ")

        flag2 = validateInput(base2)

    newBase2 = base2
    return (newBase2)


def isbase2(base2):

    try:
        base2 = int(input("Enter a base 2 number" , 2))
        flag1 = False
        return (True)
    except ValueError:
        flag1 = True
        return (False)
    else:
        flag1 = True
        return (False)

def main():

    if (printmenu(userChoice) == "2"):
        askUserValue()


main()
```

Comment: Why do you have userChoice set as a parameter for printmenu when its created inside of the method?

Comment: There are no variable declarations in Python...

Comment: btw you don't need quite so many brackets in python. Your `if`, `while` and `return` statements don't need the outer layer of brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the parameter on you printmenu() method like below:

```
def printmenu():
    flag = True

    while(flag == True):
        print("Enter 2 for base 2")
        print("Enter 8 for base 8")
        print("Enter 16 for base 16")
        userChoice = input("Enter 0 to stop: ")

        if userChoice not in ["2", "8", "16", "0"]:
            print("Invalid choice\n")
            flag = True
        else:
            flag = False
    return(userChoice)
```

Then you can call it in main:

```
if (printmenu() == "2"):
    askUserValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with how python uses variables, the variables are not the same as objects in other languages.  Variables in python are just references, so declaring them in a function doesn't actually transfer over to the main scope.  How I get around this is I declare the variable in main, and set it equal to the function that I am running.

```
userChoice = printmenu()
```

Comment: "How I get around this"... is it not worth learning how it actually works in python? This isn't a bug.

Comment: And I'm not sure what you mean that "variables are not the same as objects in other languages. Variables in Python are just references", the issue is Python scoping rules, not the semantics of variable *assignment* (note, there are no variable declarations in Python) per se.

Answer (score 0):

Use Variable length parameter :

```
def printmenu(*args):
    flag = True

    while(flag == True):
        print("Enter 2 for base 2")
        print("Enter 8 for base 8")
        print("Enter 16 for base 16")
        userChoice = input("Enter 0 to stop: ")

        if userChoice not in ["2", "8", "16", "0"]:
            print("Invalid choice\n")
            flag = True
        else:
            flag = False
    return(userChoice)
```

And use return result like this:

```
def main():

    if printmenu() == "2":
        askUserValue()


main()
```

> Second option :

Just remove the parameter and argument from the function like this :

```
def printmenu():
    flag = True

    while(flag == True):
        print("Enter 2 for base 2")
        print("Enter 8 for base 8")
        print("Enter 16 for base 16")
        userChoice = input("Enter 0 to stop: ")

        if userChoice not in ["2", "8", "16", "0"]:
            print("Invalid choice\n")
            flag = True
        else:
            flag = False
    return(userChoice)
```

and use the return value of a function like this:

```
def main():

    if printmenu() == "2":
        askUserValue()


main()
```